# Facebook Graph API returns 200 status code when try to create a post for account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a Facebook account and I want to create a post with Facebook graph API by creating an http request from a C# server.
I created an app with Facebook developer:

[image]

I tried to create a post with Facebook's Graph API Explorer as explained in
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing/

I generated a token with `pages_show_list` and `pages_read_engagement` permissions. The app ID is the result GET request for "https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0" which returned an object with `id` property.

The POST request URL is: "https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/{appId}/feed?message=hi&access_token={accessToken}"

[image]

I don't understand why I'm getting `200` status code and how can I fix it.
The error is:

```
(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \
          either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement \
          and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, \
          requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with \
          sufficient administrative permission",
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the docs, you need the following:

1. The pages_manage_posts permission
2. The pages_read_engagement permission
3. A Page access token requested by a person who is able to perform the CREATE_CONTENT task on the Page that is being queried

You are missing number one and number three, as far as I can see in your screenshot.

Btw, you can just use "/me/feed" instead, the ID is not neccessary as the Token includes it.

Comment: Done all of the above, still get this error. Any more ideas? Any test to perform to get more info?

Comment: are you trying as a user with a role in the app?